# How to automatically use Bluetooth headphones as audio output in Fedora?

Tags: linux, audio, fedora, bluetooth, gnome

When I turn on my Bluetooth headphones, I hear "connected" if my Fedora laptop is nearby, and I see the device appear in the Bluetooth settings window. If I go to the Sound settings window, however, the default audio output does not change to the Bluetooth headphones.

How can I make the audio output change to my headphones whenever the headphones connect to my laptop?

I am running Fedora 28 Workstation with GNOME 3.